# Django perform_update not updating entry

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I have a few generic DRF API views:

```
class PageCreateView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    queryset = Page.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PageSerializer
    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        text = self.request.data.get("text")
        json = generate_json(text)
        calculated_level = level_calculate(json)
        serializer.save(json=json, calculated_level=calculated_level)
        instance = super().perform_create(serializer)


class PageView(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Page.objects.select_related().all()
    serializer_class = PageSerializer
    def perform_update(self, serializer):
        text = self.request.data.get("text")
        json = generate_json(text)
        calculated_level = level_calculate(json)
        serializer.save(json=json, calculated_level=calculated_level)
        instance = super().perform_update(serializer)
```

The perform_create works perfectly.

However the perform_update does not seem to. Should I be doing something differently with the instance or the self object so that it updates the object in question?

Generating JSON and calculating the level are both metadata that are dependent on, but which I do not want to include in the POST or PUT request. They need to be re-calculated/re-generated on each save.

PageSerializer:

```
class PageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    image = Base64ImageField(max_length=None, use_url=True)
    category = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        many=False, queryset=Category.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = Page
        fields = ['date', 'intro', "text", "english",
                  "calculated_level", "json", "id", "category", "title", "image", "published", "premium"]
```

Comment: Could you add the `PageSerializer` to your post? Might be helpful. Also, is there a point in calling the `super().perform_update(serializer)`? I'm pretty sure the default `perform_update` only does `serializer.save()`, which you are literally doing the line before. It would avoid an extra save in the DB.

Comment: @JordanKowal Added PageSerializer. And ok, I can remove the last save, I wasn't sure if it was necessary or not.

Comment: Thanks. Out of curiosity, when updating, does NONE of the field gets updated correctly? or only the `json` and `calculated_level`?

Comment: @JordanKowal Actually after removing the second save, it seems to be saving correctly now.

Comment: Great, I thought it could be the case. During the `update`, the initial instance is passed to initialize the serializer. Then, you called `serializer.save(**with_extra_stuff)` which saved the instance with the serializer data and your extra data and a new instance is returned. However, you re-saved the serializer (which uses the initial instance) without the extra data, so your `json` field reverted to its original state

Comment: Also, a similar behavior might be happening in your `perform_create`. You might have been creating 2 models each time, with only the first one having the `json` data

Comment: @JordanKowal Came to write that, its double saving (and yes, probably making two copies of each on create too).  Steven, did you look at the code in `super().perform_create`?